# Reference for Wick product

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, reference-request

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space with
complexification $H_{\mathbb{C}}$. We denote by $\mathfrak{F}$ the antisymmetric Fock space
over $H_\mathbb{C}$ ("fermions"). A creation operator is denoted by $c(f)$.
I need a reference for the calculus of
$$
\langle\,\Omega ,\big(c(f_1)+c(f_1)^*\big)...\big(c(f_{2k})+c(f_{2k})^*\big)\Omega\,\rangle_{\mathfrak{F}}
$$
where $\Omega$ the unit vector, called vacuum.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is provided by the article

- Edward G. Effros and Mihai Popa, *Feynman diagrams and Wick products associated with q-Fock space*, PNAS 100 (15) (2003) 8629-8633, https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1531460100

However, the authors work in the context of $q$-Fock space. I does not know if there exists an older paper which provides the answer in the less general context of antisymmetric Fock space (i.e. q=1).

Answer (score 2):

The original reference for Wick's theorem is, not surprisingly, Wick's original 1950 paper: [*The Evaluation of the Collision Matrix*](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.80.268) published in the Physical Review **80** (2) pp. 268-272.  He also shows how to compute it and it is surprisingly readable 60 years on.

Of course, depending on your background, this may be too physical.  A more mathematical reference are the Bombay Lectures by Kac and Raina *[Highest-weight representations of infinite-dimensional Lie algebras](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SZVqYvvD8rQC)*, particularly the 5th lecture on the Bose-Fermi correspondence.

The basic idea is to think of $\mathfrak{F}$ as the space of semi-infinite forms.  The vacuum vector would be given by
$$\Omega = f_1^* \wedge f_2^* \wedge \cdots$$
and $c(f_i)^*$ acts by wedging with $f_i^*$ whereas $c(f_i)$ acts by contracting with $f_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
In fact, I only need the result of the calculation (and locate the reference). Indeed, I believe that the calculus of this quantity is classical.
My background is a very basic knowledge of $q$-fock space ($-1\leq q \leq 1$). 
The first reference is too physical. The context of the second is unfortunately far from my knowledge...

Comment: It would perhaps help to know precisely what you are asking.  What are the $f_i$?  Are they linearly independent, or simply any vectors in $H_{\mathbb{C}}$?  And what canonical anticommutation relations are you using?  The $q$-deformed ones or the standard ones?

Comment: The $f_i$ are any vectors in $H_\mathbb{C}$.

I use the standard relations (q=-1):
$$
c(f)^{*}c(e)+c(e)c(f)^{*} = <f,e>Id
$$


Answer (score 2):

The article *[Wick products of the CAR algebra](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-98-05028-X)* by E. R. Negrin provides the required formula for the antisymmetric Fock space
in the corollary on page 3644.

I want to point out that the Wick products (for the antisymmetric Fock space) can be constructed from a Gaussian generating function
which is Gaussian in (real) Grassmann variables, which is given for the case presented in the question by:

$G(\mathbf{\xi}) = exp((\Sigma_{i=0}^{2k} \xi_i f_i, \Sigma_{j=0}^{2k} \xi_j f_j))$

where $( , )$ denotes the Hilbert sapce $H_\mathbb{C}$ inner product.

The required Wick product is obtained as the coefficient of $\xi_1 \xi_2 . . .\xi_{2k}$.

Answer (score 2):

One should be able to obtain the formula from the appendix of:

- Hellmut Baumgärtel, Matthias Jurke, Fernando Lledó, *Twisted duality of the CAR-Algebra*, J.Math.Phys. 43 (2002) 4158-4179, https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1483376, http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0204029

They have a formula for all vectors, to the vacuum expectation just the summand with $2p=n$ contributes. They using Arakis self dual CAR algebra, and if you consider $a(f)$ for $f=\Gamma f$ it should equal your $c(f)+c(f)^\ast$.